# IIS 503 Error - The Module DLL C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\main.dll failed to load. The data is the error

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5

In a working `Windows Server 2012 R2`, today I Encounter The error.

`The Module DLL C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\main.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.`

the eventID is : 2280

and this one

```
A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '#' serving application pool 'AppPoolName' 
reported a listener channel failure.
```

The sites running on IIS get a 503 error. also there is no `main.dll` file in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\main.dll`

there is not more in error logs.

how can i fix the error?

also the request is not received by IIS App(i mean my code), i test it by creating a new directory for temp files, and there is nothing generated at the Directory, showing that iis stops the request in initial phases. so there is nothing in code to change

[image]

Comment: You have to track down the source of that dll. It is not part of IIS, so really weird that it is there.

Comment: how can i track down that file?

Comment: That’s rather specific to a file. You might start from its detailed information from file properties in Windows Explorer, but what’s next varies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the iis_iusrs and iusr user full control permission to that dll. if you are using IIS Shared Configuration and the IIS is creating 'Service Unavailable' errors and the AppPools are going down, this can be a symptom of the system configuration is out of sync which is corrupting the shared configuration.

open iis and check module which module is using mail.dll. I can't see mail.dll under this location C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv.